# Javascript multiply on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, onclick

I want to have a default value (10 for example) and a button to increase it by the same value on every click.. I can't get script to work

```
<div id="output">10</div>
<div id="increase">Increase</div>

<script>
$('#increase').click(function() {
var one = $('#output').val();
var increase = 10;
var output = +one + increase;

$('#output').val(output.toFixed(2));
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = value;
});
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t5ud192g/3/

Comment: It would help if you included jQuery in the jsfiddle. Then look in the browser's error console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include jQuery and set try this code:

```
    $('#increase').click(function() {
      var one = $('#output').text();
      var increase = 10;
      var output = Number(one) + increase;

      $('#output').text(output.toFixed(2));

    });
```

Take a look at the `Number(one)`, to convert a string to a number.

**EDIT**
Use the [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function to get/set the value from div.

Comment: `+one` does the same as `Number(one)`.

Comment: Yes, thats true. If you include jQuery in your jsFiddle and work with `var one = $('#output').html();` it should works.

Answer (score 0):

You have used `val` instead of `text`.
Something like this should work:

```
$('#increase').click(function() {
  var one = $('#output').text();
  var increase = 10;
  var output = +one + increase;

  $('#output').text(output.toFixed(2));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add jQuery in fiddle.

```
 var outputRef = $('#output'),increase = 10;
      $('#increase').click(function() {
          var output = Number(outputRef.text()) + increase;
          outputRef.text(output);
        });
```

Comment: Because you take the value of `output` outside the function, it will work only once.

Comment: I supposed that he wanted to make a counter , in which he first wanted to take initial value of output only once & increase the counter with increase value.

Comment: Yes, that's what he wanted, but that's not what your code does.

Comment: What's my code doing ?? What is benefit of parsing DOM again & again for getting output value??

Answer (score 0):

Use .text() to get the value of a div, .val() is for form inputs:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#increase').click(function() {
        var one = $('#output').text();
        var increase = 10;
        var output = +one + increase;

        $('#output').text(output.toFixed(2));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First you nee to load jQuery from a CDN e.g.: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.js and then:

```
$('#increase').click(function() {
  var one = parseInt($('#output').text());
  var increase = 10;
  var output = increase + one;

  $('#output').text(output.toFixed(2));
});
```

Instead of val() use the text() because the element you pulling data from is not an input. Thats it, the modified code above works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

)
The guys have nailed it - but I reckon you are learning - and you asked about a button - so couple of pointers.

I would use input for anything coming from user, and also makes a nice button.

```
<input type="text" id="output" value=10 /> 
<input type="button" id="increase" value="Increase">

$('#increase').click(function() {
var rtn;  // I would avoid same variable name as element in HTML ..pers pref
rtn = +$("#output").val() + 10;  // Using inputs, can access the val
$('#output').val(rtn);
});
```

Enjoy JavaScript -I'm loving it :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. I was thinking about using input or submit button, but what is the actual upside of that?

Comment: well ....  I am not an expert - but without any CSS, it will display as button/text in HTML(5), with javascript disabled, it will still display as a button/text.  I find it easier to look through my code and identify buttons etc.    You can style all your buttons etc without alocating classes.